Creating and using dynamic variables based on a dynamic component
I have a table as a component, and now I am trying to build a column wise search within it.
The table that will be created will have a dynamic number of columns. Hence I need to create multiple variables for binding with the search input. I was trying to create those variables with eval (unsuccessfully, because I cannot use eval with svelte functionalities like writable or $:).
Note: the main restrictions I have are,

the the dynamic variable has to be declared as writable('')
create columns has to be in a function (as I have to recreate them for other conditions), but the search columns needs to be outside the function, as it will be used across the page
the number of total columns and the number of searchable columns are dynamic
the full functionality is much more huge and complex, hence shared a small part of it, where I need some support

Note: Doing first time front end development, coming from Mainframes backend dev.
I have tried to replicate my scenario in the below repl (not working.. but you will get gist):
https://svelte.dev/repl/42335b2b121a402da1c5cd6c826bb5df?version=4.2.19
Expectation:
Need the value from any of those inputs to $searchColumn and the corresponding column value. Based on this I will use it to perform next set of tasks. Please see a working version of the scenario but with static defined variables:
https://svelte.dev/repl/fa3bd4c83d53421ea0eb3ae5936b401c?version=4.2.19

When you think you need dynamic variables you can practically always use an array, object, or Map.

I wish it is as simple as using an array, object or a map. Here I am trying to get the value from multiple components that are bound and need those variables declared as writable

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It seems to me that if you know that the dynamic variables will be a Writable store then there's no reason not to put them inside of an object or array and subscribe to them inside your Search component.
Based on your provided REPLs I came to this solution using the classic Svelte Context with Stores to update the column and searchColumn variables from the Search component whenever the input value changes. Unfortunately the typeWorkaround you included messes up with Svelte's reactivity so I wouldn't recommend using it (same for using eval()).
This is what the functionality code I think you're looking for looks like in a REPL
App.svelte
<script>
    import { setContext } from 'svelte';
    import Search from './SearchPretend.svelte'
    import { get, writable } from 'svelte/store';
    import Subscribe from './Subscribe.svelte';

    let externalImpacts = false;
    let customComponent = [];
    let column = writable(0)
    let searchColumn = writable('');
    let searchableColumns = {}

    setContext("searchColumn", searchColumn)
    setContext("column", column)

    function createColumns() {
        customComponent = [
            {accessor: 'Col 0'},
            {accessor: 'Col 1', search: true},
            {accessor: 'Col 2', search: true},
            {accessor: 'Col 3'},
            {accessor: 'Col 4'},
            {accessor: 'Col 5', search: true},
            {accessor: 'Col 6', search: true},
            {accessor: 'Col 7', search: true}
        ]
        
        //loop through object right after creating the columns
        customComponent.forEach((obj, i) => {
                let searchColName = 'searchColumn_' + i;
                if (obj.search === true) {
                        searchableColumns[searchColName] = writable("")
                }
        })
    }
    
    $: createColumns(), externalImpacts;

    function updateColumnWithSearch() {
        
        customComponent.forEach((obj, i) => {
            let searchColName = searchableColumns[`searchColumn_${i}`];
            if (obj.search === true) {
                obj.extra = {
                        //no problem using get method since this function runs reactively
                        searchColumn: get(searchColName)
                }
            }
        })

        //reassign array to itself to trigger Svelte reactivity
        customComponent = customComponent
    }
    
    $: if ($searchColumn !== undefined) {
        updateColumnWithSearch()
        externalImpacts
    }
</script>

<h2>
    Value: <code>{$searchColumn} </code>
</h2>
<h3>
    Column No: <code>{$column}</code>
</h3>
<h3>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------   </h3>


<div class="inputs">
    <!-- loop on customComponent to then filter off searchable columns -->
    {#each customComponent as column, i}
        <!-- use same criteria as in the forEach loop on line 38 -->
        {#if column.search === true}
            <Search bind:value={searchableColumns[`searchColumn_${i}`]} index={i}/>
            <Subscribe value={searchableColumns[`searchColumn_${i}`]}/>
        {/if}
    {/each}
</div>

<style> 
.inputs {
  column-count: 5;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>

Since you know the value must be a writable store, just subscribe in the Search component and update the context from within
SearchPretend.svelte
<script>
    import { getContext } from "svelte";
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";

    export let value = writable('')
    export let index

    let searchColumn = getContext('searchColumn')
    let column = getContext('column')

    function updateContext() {
        $column = index
        $searchColumn = $value
    }
</script>

<div>
    <input bind:value={$value} on:input={updateContext}/>
</div>

If you need to display the subscription to the dynamic variable as plain text, you can just use a very simple Subscribe component like this
Subscribe.svelte
<script>
    export let value
</script>

{$value}

I tried to clarify some stuff with comments but let me know if I wasn't clear, hope this helps you implement the feature!

This was really helpful. Thanks. I had few minor hiccups when implementing your solution, (1) the index was returned undefined (i did not have patience to debug but anyway i had to change it to accessor name, so went with the slightly different approach for it. (2) I skipped the plain text subscribe, as the dynamic store fits for both my requirements. Thanks again.

That's awesome! I'm glad I helped you find your solution :)
